# UDF does not work with cell references if locale changed

Tags: c#, excel, localization, excel-addins, udf

I wrote a C# COM (Automation) add-in which I am testing with Excel 2010 x64, running on Windows 7.  It defines a number of user-defined formulae.  Let's take an example UDF that has two strings as arguments, called first with literals and then with cell references:

```
=MyFunction("A","B")
=MyFunction(A1,B1)
```

If Regional Settings = English then these both work.

If I set Regional Settings to French and re-open the workbook, Excel has changed the formulae to:

```
=MyFunction("A";"B")
=MyFunction(A1;B1)
```

The first one (with literals) still works.  The second one now does **not** work = it just returns `#VALUE!` and my managed UDF code is not even called (debugging with Visual Studio 2010).

Why is this?

Comment: Regional system settings aside for a moment, is the regional machine on `xlA1` or `xlR1C1` formula reference style?

Comment: It's on `xlA1` reference style.

Comment: But it behaves the same if I switch to R1C1 style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this behaviour is different depending on regional settings, but anyway:

The UDF signature was like this:

```cs
public object MyFunction(string arg1, string arg2)
{
```

I then just use arg1 and arg2 in the code.  As I said, this works with cell references in the English locale.  In the French locale, it works if I refactor it to look like this:

```cs
public object MyFunction(object ref1, object ref2)
{
    string arg1 = (ref1 is Range) ? (string)((Range)ref1).Value : (string)ref1;
    string arg2 = (ref2 is Range) ? (string)((Range)ref2).Value : (string)ref2;
```

That's going to require quite a lot of changes... anyone know why English settings allow the type conversion to happen before it reaches the UDF?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set en-US culture explicitly so UDF work correctly on different locales, e.g.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

somewhere at the start of your add-in